# Saving to database via AJAX/jQuery, sending two variables

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, contenteditable

I have this problem that I have multiple fields that updates a database via an AJAX-call. The AJAX call looks like this:

```
$(".fresheditable").fresheditor("save", function (id, parsedHtml) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'save.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            id: id,
            parsedHtml: parsedHtml
        }
    });
});
```

The ID value changes depending on what element is being edited. The problem is when the update gets sent to the `save.php` document. How do I only run the update with the specific ID?

See my save.php:

```
if($_POST['id']='link') 
{
    $link = $_POST['parsedHtml']; //get posted data

    // query
    $sql = "UPDATE buttons SET linkname=? WHERE id=?";
    $q = $conn->prepare($sql);

    if ($q->execute(array($link,$_SESSION['button'])))
    {
        echo 1;
    }
}

//The next if-statement could look like this:

if($_POST['id']='contactperson') 
{
    $contactperson = $_POST['parsedHtml']; //get posted data

    // query
    $sql = "UPDATE buttons SET contactperson=? WHERE id=?";
    $q = $conn->prepare($sql);

    if ($q->execute(array($contactperson,$_SESSION['button'])))
    {
        echo 1;
    }
}
```

If more than one ID is sent to the `save.php` say `link` and `contactperson` both if-statements are true and the update sets the same values because the `parsedHtml` variable.

Is there anything I can do in `save.php` that can prevent this? Somehow I need to associate the correct `parsedHtml` with the corresponding `id`.

Comment: How the value of `id` can be `contactperson` and `link` at the same time?

Comment: My only idea is that the script sends the value as many times as the number of the elements being edited.

Comment: It doesn't matter, each time an element is being edited - a new request is being sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comparison operator in PHP (as well as in Javascript) is `==` and not `=`

```
if($_POST["id"]=="link")
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it because you're using single equals in your IF tests, which assigns and returns true as a value exists? Not double-equals for comparison?

E.g.

```
if($_POST['id']=='link')
```

not

```
if($_POST['id']='link')
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can use is data attribute i mean

`<span item-data="some_id">data</span>` now you can select in jquery, the specific item-data from your html to update.

Answer (score -1):

Use else-if structure.

```
if($_POST['id']='link') {

}
else if($_POST['id']='contactperson') {

}
```

Comment: Problem with this is that it both cases, this will be true. The script send the ID once for every item that is editable